# MineSweeping. I have problem in printing out the map

Tags: c

I am doing a project about making minesweeping with pointer.
Here is my code in the initialmap & Printmap function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX_ROW 5
#define MAX_COL 5

void initialmap(char *Minemap[][7],char *Playermap[][7]){
    //playermap
    int row,col;
    for(row=1;row<MAX_ROW+1;row++){
        for(col=1;col<MAX_COL+1;col++){
            *(Playermap+row)+col=="*";
        }
    }

    //minemap
    for(row=1;row<=MAX_ROW-1;row++){
        for(col=1;col<=MAX_COL-1;col++){
            (*(Minemap+row)+col)=="0";
        }
    }

    //place mines
    int i;
    for(i=1;i<=5;i++){
        int minerow=rand() % (5-1+1)+1;
        int minecol=rand() % (5-1+1)+1;

        if((*(Minemap+minerow)+minecol)=="0")
           (*(Minemap+minerow)+minecol)=="1" ;        
    }
}

void Printmap(char *Playermap[7][7]) {
    int row,col;
    printf("  0 1 2 3 4 \n");
    printf("  - - - - -\n");
    for(row=1;row<6;row++){
        printf("%d|",row-1);
        for(col=1;col<6;col++){
            printf("%c ",(*(Playermap+row)+col));
        }
        printf("\n");    
    }
}
```

Then I get the warning
[Warning] comparison of distinct pointer types lacks a cast

Can anybody help me to understand this concept? Thanks~

Comment: Where do you get the warning?

Comment: This seems wrong: `(*(Minemap+minerow)+minecol)=="1"`. Also other instances of the same problem.

Comment: Your question would be easier to understand if you specified to which line the warning message refers.

Comment: You can't use `==` to compare or to assign string values.

Comment: Is the map really a 2D array of `char*` pointers? or a 2D array of `char`? Please post the full code to show how the arrays are are defined.

Comment: `"0"` is very different of `'0'` I think you mix string and char

Answer (score 1):

In looking at your code it appears you are attempting to populate two 5 x 5 character grids to start out.  As noted in the comments there are a few issues noted with character assignment versus testing.  But instead of belaboring that point, I will incorporate those comments into the following sample code that you might want to analyze and consider.  Since your sample does not include your "main" function, I pieced together a simple function to allow for the illustrations of my suggested changes.

Following is a revised version of your code keeping the spirit of your player and map initialization.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX_ROW 5
#define MAX_COL 5

void initialmap(char Minemap[MAX_ROW][MAX_COL],char Playermap[MAX_ROW][MAX_COL])
{
    //playermap
    int row,col;
    for(row=0; row<MAX_ROW; row++) /* Started loops at zero - usual and customary */
    {
        for(col=0; col<MAX_COL; col++)
        {
            Playermap[row][col] = '*';  /* Store a character - not a string */
        }
    }

    //minemap
    for(row=0; row<=MAX_ROW; row++)
    {
        for(col=0; col<=MAX_COL; col++)
        {
            Minemap[row][col] = '0'; /* Store a character - not a string */
        }
    }

    //place mines
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<MAX_ROW; i++)
    {
        int minerow=rand() % (MAX_ROW)+1;
        int minecol=rand() % (MAX_COL)+1;

        if(Minemap[minerow][minecol] == '0')
            Minemap[minerow][minecol] = '1' ;
    }
}

void Printmap(char Playermap[MAX_ROW][MAX_COL])
{
    int row,col;
    printf("  0 1 2 3 4 \n");
    printf("  - - - - -\n");
    for(row=0; row<MAX_ROW; row++)
    {
        printf("%d|",row);
        for(col=0; col<MAX_COL; col++)
        {
            printf("%c ", Playermap[row][col]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    char Player[MAX_ROW][MAX_COL];
    char Mapp [MAX_ROW][MAX_COL];

    initialmap(Mapp, Player);

    printf("Player\n");
    Printmap(Player);
    printf("\nMap\n");
    Printmap(Mapp);

    return 0;
}
```

First off, wherever there was a reference to row and column size, I substituted your defined values "MAX_ROW" and "MAX_COL" into the locations where you had hard-coded values (e.g. "5").  Next, in the functions where you were wanting to pass in a reference to a two-dimensional character array, I just made the reference to the arrays' pointers and noted the dimensions for the function to use in order to simplify things.  Then, since arrays normally start with at element "0" (or [0][0] in the case of these two-dimensional arrays), I revised the various for loops to also start a "0" making it more conventional to analyze.

In the "main" function, I just created a few lines of code to call the initialization function and then printed out a copy of the player array and the map array.  The sample looked like the following on my terminal.

```
    Player
  0 1 2 3 4 
  - - - - -
0|* * * * * 
1|* * * * * 
2|* * * * * 
3|* * * * * 
4|* * * * * 

Map
  0 1 2 3 4 
  - - - - -
0|0 0 0 0 0 
1|0 0 0 0 0 
2|0 0 0 1 0 
3|0 1 0 0 0 
4|0 1 1 0 0
```

I guess the main take-away from these changes are that arrays, be it single dimension arrays or multi-dimension arrays are a definition for a chunk of memory and the array name is in effect the name of the pointer containing the memory address of the array.  Give this a try to see if it moves your project along.  There probably will be comments either correcting some things I've explained or someone might provide another method for calling your functions.  By all means review those comments as well as they can be further use to you.

I hope that helps.

Regards.